# segmentation fault on shared memory

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, shared-memory

I'm having some hard time with the shared memory, I get segmentation fault when I try to see what's inside a variable

`printf("|%d|", mappa->map[i][j]->taxi);`

but not when I'm writing on it

`mappa->map[i][j]->taxi = rand() % 10;`

my first guess was: ok I'm not allocating enough space. But wouldn't fail also the instruction when trying to write on "taxi"?

PS I need to have "taxi" inside a struct because later I will have more elements in that struct

```
#define KEY 6666

typedef struct cell {
    int taxi;
} cell;
typedef cell *cella;

typedef struct city
{
    cella map[5][5];
} city;

typedef city *citta;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    citta mappa;
    cella single_cell;
    int id_mappa;
    int id_cell;
    id_mappa = shmget(KEY, sizeof(*mappa), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    mappa = shmat(id_mappa, NULL, 0);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            printf("ciao\n");
            id_cell = shmget(KEY + i + j, sizeof(*single_cell), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
            mappa->map[i][j] = shmat(id_cell, NULL, 0);
            mappa->map[i][j]->taxi = rand() % 10;
            printf("|%d|", mappa->map[i][j]->taxi);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("-------------\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when doing :

```
id_cell = shmget(KEY + i + j, sizeof(*single_cell), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
```

you use several times the same key, in the first turn of the loop *i* and *j* are 0 so the used key is `KEY + 0 + 0` being `KEY` already used for *mappa* and then on the first turn of the loop `mappa->map[i][j] = shmat(id_cell, NULL, 0);` is 'like' to do `mappa->map[i][j] = mappa` then `mappa->map[i][j]->taxi = rand() % 10;` does not have the expected behavior for instance setting `mappa->map[i][j]`with the random value which is not a valid pointer when you try to dereference it next line to print the value of `mappa->map[i][j]->taxi`.

Do for instance :

```
id_cell = shmget(KEY + i + j*10 + 1, sizeof(*single_cell), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
```

to have a different key each time (you can just multiply *j* by 5 of course, or more simple use a var you increment each time you call *shmget* etc)

```
after that :#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define KEY 6666

typedef struct cell {
    int taxi;
} cell;
typedef cell *cella;

typedef struct city
{
    cella map[5][5];
} city;

typedef city *citta;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    citta mappa;
    cella single_cell;
    int id_mappa;
    int id_cell;
    id_mappa = shmget(KEY, sizeof(*mappa), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    mappa = shmat(id_mappa, NULL, 0);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            printf("ciao\n");
            id_cell = shmget(KEY + i + j*10 + 1, sizeof(*single_cell), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
            mappa->map[i][j] = shmat(id_cell, NULL, 0);
            mappa->map[i][j]->taxi = rand() % 10;
            printf("|%d|", mappa->map[i][j]->taxi);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("-------------\n");
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
ciao
|3|ciao
|5|ciao
|0|ciao
|9|ciao
|5|
ciao
|0|ciao
|7|ciao
|8|ciao
|3|ciao
|1|
ciao
|3|ciao
|2|ciao
|7|ciao
|0|ciao
|1|
ciao
|4|ciao
|4|ciao
|5|ciao
|2|ciao
|0|
ciao
|8|ciao
|2|ciao
|6|ciao
|4|ciao
|1|
-------------
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

and

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==8741== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8741== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8741== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8741== Command: ./a.out
==8741== 
ciao
|3|ciao
|2|ciao
|7|ciao
|6|ciao
|3|
ciao
|5|ciao
|8|ciao
|1|ciao
|9|ciao
|2|
ciao
|3|ciao
|7|ciao
|9|ciao
|0|ciao
|3|
ciao
|9|ciao
|1|ciao
|3|ciao
|9|ciao
|5|
ciao
|8|ciao
|6|ciao
|1|ciao
|3|ciao
|1|
-------------
==8741== 
==8741== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8741==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8741==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==8741== 
==8741== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8741== 
==8741== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==8741== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

Out of that to hide the pointers through *typedef* (example `typedef cell *cella;`) is a very bad idea producing a lot of problem and making your code less readable, I strongly encourage you to let the `*`  visible.

Comment: yes the key was definitely the biggest issue and I didn't consider that it would start at key. Although now the problem is still there, as soon as the I get incremented to 1

Comment: @MarcoA7 that means you still reuse the same key, as you can see above with the fix there is no problem

Comment: @MarcoA7 or of course the code you execute is not the previous more the fix, but a different one, and in that case I cannot help you

Comment: I don't know what to say, on an online compiler works, on my machine it doesn't

Comment: @MarcoA7 seems you have an undefined behavior, what is your new version ? did you tried using mine by copy/paste just adding needed #includes ?

Comment: I'm running this code https://pastebin.com/3u2XVSZ4 on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler. on my machine I use the same code and compiled with gcc city.c -o city and running it with ./city basic stuffs

Comment: @MarcoA7 I just edited my answer to put the full code

Comment: on ubuntu works perfectly on my mac no, I guess something is wrong but anyway I'm gonna mark your answer as correct

Comment: @MarcoA7 yes is strange, all seems ok even your code as I said is difficult to read because of the typedef and the fact the var *single_cell* is here for nothing except to do a *sizeof* you can do in an other way

Comment: @MarcoA7 I had a mac in past, but it is dead, I cannot do a test on. Currently I am on a PI4 raspbian